# Почему ввод переменной типа string с помощью getline не работает?

Tags: c++, строки, input, getline

Ввод данных о первой коробке срабатывает без ошибок. Но начиная со второй не происходит ввод названия (arr[i].name) - ввод просто пропускается и начинается ввод последующий данных. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct CandyBar {
    string name;
    double weight;
    int calories;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    CandyBar arr[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите название " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        getline(cin, arr[i].name);
        cout << "Введите вес " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        cin >> arr[i].weight;
        cout << "Введите число каллорий " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        cin >> arr[i].calories;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Данные о " << i + 1 << " коробке:\n";
        cout << "Название: " << arr[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Вес: " << arr[i].weight << endl;
        cout << "Число калорий: " << arr[i].calories << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}<br>
```

Comment: "После числового ввода надо добавить cin.get()" - это не будет работать, если кто-то после ввода числа добавит еще несколько символов (например, пробелов) перед нажатием клавиши "Ввод".

Comment: @AnT а что тогда делать? В других ответах видел способ: cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');Но у меня почему-то выскакивает 4 ошибки и помечается как ошибка max. Можете посоветовать, что с этим делать?

Comment: @AnT уберите пометку вопроса как дубликат. В других вопросах я не нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Может кто-то что-нибудь предложит или подскажет

Comment: Не смешивайте чтение `getline()` с `>>`. / (или по крайней мере всегда вызывайте getline после всех `>>` (дело в том, что getline "глотает" разделитель ("`\n`"), а `>>` нет. Вот они вместе и не дружат))

Comment: @avp Спасибо) Я уже разобрался

Comment: Каким образом вы могли "не найти" там ответа?? `cin.ignore` - это ответ. А то, что у вас "выскакивают ошибки", никакого отношения к теме не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

cin >> оставляет \n в потоке из-за чего getline() впоследствии не считывает строку, т.к. натыкается на \n и заканчивает свою работу. Чтобы решить эту проблему можно воспользоваться следующим методом:

```
#include <limits>
//...
//тут cin >>
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Или просто посимвольно читать до `\n` (а потом не забыть проверить на EOF)

Comment: Не понял. Вы сами заявили в комментариях, что не смогли найти ответа по ссылкам на дубликаты. И вдруг в качестве ответа здесь вы приводите ответ фактически скопированный оттуда. В чем дело? И почему снята ссылка на дубликаты? И сколько можно задавать это заезженный вопрос?