# Проблемы с функцией puts

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct BooksInfo
{
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int pages;
    int year;
};
int main (void)
{
    char d[2];
    int ctr,quantily;
    puts("Сколько книг вы хотите заполнить?");
    scanf (" %d", &quantily);
    struct BooksInfo books[quantily];
    for (ctr=0;ctr<quantily;ctr++)
    {
        puts ("Какое название у книги?");
        fgets(books[ctr].name,50,stdin);
        puts ("Какой автор книги?");
        fgets(books[ctr].author,50,stdin);
        puts ("Сколько страниц в книге?");
        scanf(" %d",&books[ctr].pages);
        puts ("Какого года книжка?");
        scanf(" %d",&books[ctr].year);
    }


    return 0 ;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде все правильно, но возникли проблемы, скорее всего с функцией puts. Проблема на изображении.

Comment: Почему в качестве размера буфера в `fgets` передается `quantily`??? При чем там `quantily` вообще??? Также в С++ не разрешается `struct BooksInfo books[quantily];`. Почему на вопросе стоит тэг [C++]?

Comment: ой, ща исправим, но с gets абсолютно такая же проблема была

Comment: это тоже исправим, не думал что и в этом си будет отличаться от си++

Comment: Так а в чем именно проблема-то? Что такое "возникли проблемы"? Что именно мы должны увидеть на ваших скриншотах?

Comment: Так я же картинку загрузил, на ней видно что сразу после "Какое название книги?" следует "какой автор книги?", почему первый fgets пропустился?

Comment: А, вот оно что... Откуда же мы по скриншоту может определить, что он "пропустился"? Что-то вы косяками идете с одной и той же проблемой.

Comment: Понятно, поругались поругались, да и отметили вопрос как дубликат. Вас случаем не Гена зовут?

Comment: Не "поругались", а вытащили клещами из ленивого автора более-менее осмысленное описание проблемы, которое он не удосужился предоставить сразу. Пометку я снял, ибо имеющиеся у меня под руками ответы-дупликаты - по С++, а у вас С. Однако это не меняет того факта, что ваш вопрос - заезженный донельзя дупликат, который здесь уже порядком поднадоел (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992550/Почему-ввод-переменной-типа-string-с-помощью-getline-не-работает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `scanf("%d",...)` не читает из входного потока символ перевода строки, который вы ввели сразу за цифрами вашего числа. Именно этот символ перевода строки `\n`, оставшийся в буфере, и вызывает "пропуск" вашего первого `fgets`. Ваш первый `fgets` сразу обнаруживает во входном потоке это `\n`, читает его из входного потока и завершает работу. Это создает иллюзию того, что первый `fgets` "пропускается".

1. Либо [чистите входной буфер](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) перед переходом от форматированного ввода к построчному

   ```
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
     /* discard */;
   ```
2. Либо (лучше!) перестаньте вообще смешивать форматированный и построчный ввод. Раз хотите использовать `fgets` - значит везде используйте `fgets`. Никакого `scanf("%d",...)`

   ```
   puts("Сколько книг вы хотите заполнить?");
   char strq[64];
   fgets(strq, sizeof strq, stdin); // <-- добавить проверку успешности
   sscanf(strq, "%d", &quantily);   // <-- но лучше `strtod`
   ```

Также имейте в виду, что функция `fgets` сохраняет в прочитанную строку и символ `\n` тоже. Его наличие в полях `name` и `author` может оказаться для вас неожиданным. Чтобы убрать из строки это `\n` после `fgets` обычно делают

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

или нечто аналогичное.

P.S. К функции `puts` все это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: короче говоря, puts после себя оставляет '\n', gets его кушает и завершается? Проще тогда будет после puts поставить getchar который и скушает этот пропуск строки. Я только дочитываю книжку грега перри , а вы тут мне даете какой-то ссканф с каким-то непонятным массивом который че-то там делает. Спасибо вам конечно, но я думаю вы заметили названия моих программ)

Comment: @Дмитрий Крайзер: "puts после себя оставляет..."? Вы мой ответ читали??? `puts` ничего нигде не оставляет. `puts` тут совершенно ни при чем. Перестаньте обижать наш `puts`. Простой `getchar` скушает только один символ. А у вас их там в общем случае может быть много. Что касается "названий ваших программ"... Если вы уже дошли до номера 51, то, я думаю, можно уже и со `sscanf` ознакомиться.

Comment: То есть после ввода в сканф числа, '\n' в него не записывается, а идет гулять по программе и ждать следующего вызова функции, что примет этот пропуск?

Comment: @Дмитрий Крайзер: Именно так. `scanf("%d",...)` читает до первого нечислового символа. Можете попробовать ввести для него `2vasya` и нажать `Enter`. Вы увидите, что в `quantily` прочитается значение `2`, а `vasya` и `\n` останутся сидеть в буфере до первого `fgets`.

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо вам, просто изначально не мог вникнуть в ответ) Этот вопрос на случай, если вас зовут Геной: КОГДА БУДЕТ ГОТОВ САЙТ????

Comment: @Дмитрий Крайзер: Меня зовут не Геной.

Comment: Показалось значит, никнейм у вас схож с одним негодяем - https://www.youtube.com/user/ANTGPRO

Comment: и еще раз огромное вам спасибо за такой развернутый ответ:)